# bun runtime doesnt work with SKD ably javascript starting v2.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, publish-subscribe, bun

This question is about the new update of the ably SKD javascript library

Hey, Is there anything Im missing out? - my typescript code stop working with the new ably version library. Things to consider:
-Ably Version 1.2.50
-Bun installed
-Keep reading for package.json

```
import * as Ably from 'ably';
// const Ably = require('ably')
// For the full code sample see here: https://github.com/ably/quickstart-js
const ably = new Ably.Realtime(process.env.ABLY_API_KEY);
await ably.connection.once('connected');
console.log('Connected to Ably!');
const to_rec = ably.channels.get('TEST')

await to_rec.subscribe((message) => {
    console.log('inside subscribe')
    console.log('message received for event ' + message.name);
    console.log('message data:' + message.data);
  });
```

```
import * as Ably from 'ably';
// const Ably = require('ably')
// For the full code sample see here: https://github.com/ably/quickstart-js
const ably = new Ably.Realtime(process.env.ABLY_API_KEY);

await ably.connection.once('connected');
console.log('Connected to Ably!');
const to_test = ably.channels.get('TEST')
await to_test.publish('greeting', 'hello!');
```

This same code works if run in node and ably version ^2.0.0

```
{
  "name": "DOES NOT WORK",
  "module": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bun": "latest"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ably": "^2.0.1",
    "hono": "^4.1.3",
    "pm2": "^5.3.1",
    "redis": "^4.6.13"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "DOES WORK!",
  "module": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@flydotio/dockerfile": "latest",
    "@types/bun": "latest"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cloudamqp/amqp-client": "^3.1.1",
    "ably": "1.2.50",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "hono": "^4.1.3",
    "redis": "^4.6.13"
  }
}
```

I had run the sample file (sub_ex.mjs and pub_ex.mjs) codes with other extension files and runtimes.
So far I have tried with .mjs, .ts, .js. and with node runtime, bun runtime
v1.2.50 works with all extensions and both runtimes
v2.0.0 // v2.0.1 only works with .mjs and node